add data to specific row and colum in csv python
I have this code which I want to add data from the user input to each column and rows:
import csv
import datetime
import calendar

days = [i for i in range(1,32,1)]
days = (','.join(map(str,days))).strip() # To remove square brackets
field = ['fingerprint', 'month', 'year',days]

for i in range(4):
    finger1 = input("input the fingerprints: ")
    finger = ''.join(finger1)
year = input("Enter Year")
month = input("enter month")


def main():
    with open('shoft.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        add = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='/')
        add.writerow(field)
        add.writerows(finger)
    
def addRow():
    pass
    
def addColumn():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

As I want to ask for times for 4 users to add their fingerprint number then it adds them to fingerprint column in four rows, then add year which same for all four rows with month And for days it automatically adds x for one and 6 for next day except Fridays should be always x. days numbers it should be just number but couldn't find solution to remove quotes other than adding escapechar with slash.
like this :
code,month,year,1,2,3,4,5,6,..31
c633,5    ,2024,x,6,x,6... 
c600,5    ,2024,6,x,6,x..

I mean how I control it to tell the user input goes to specific row and column and adds data automatically to days column.

Interesting question, however I'm having difficultly understanding how the 'days' columns are to be populated. Can you please clarify?

Can you give an example of what the user input should look like and how the consequential CSV file should appear? As it stands, I'm afraid your question doesn't make a lot of sense

ask user to enter year one time and it goes under year column on four rows also month same thing because this two column is not changing one input is enough, but fingerprint column will change for every four row. for days it should record auto.

@SIGHUP for example when user input 2024 for year then four rows for year column will be added but for fingerprint four user have different fingerprint code.

This the original file i want to create this one with python. https://1drv.ms/x/c/44aab7e9126c4034/EXVUzZnF-AdPl7wZQEn86VMBP7BcrHSPQp5StRrItMFhwQ

What do you do for months that have 28, 29, or 30 days? Some rows alternate x,6 and other 6,x.  How is it determined?

Here's an attempt to answer the question with the vague requirements.  I will update if more information becomes available.  Comment if anything is unclear.
To write rows with the csv module, make a list of the column items.  No need to add your own commas. In this case, make sure the header is a list of 34 items and each row of data is a list of 34 items.  The csv module will convert items in the lists to their string representation before writing them to a file, so you can use any object (int, float, string, etc.) in the lists.
import csv
import datetime as dt

FRIDAY = 4

# 34 columns total indexed 0-33
# The * expands the range in-place as 1,2,3...31
header = ['fingerprint', 'month', 'year', *range(1,32)]

year = int(input('Enter year: '))
month = int(input('Enter month: '))

with open('shoft.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for f in range(4):
        finger = input('input the fingerprints: ')
        # How 6,x order was determined wasn't specified.
        # I chose alternating the output
        if f % 2:
            d1, d2 = 6, 'x'
        else:
            d1, d2 = 'x', 6
        # Again, * expands [d1,d2]*15 in-place.
        # e.g. 6,x,6,x...6 or x,6,x,6...x
        # creates a length 34 list for row.
        row = [finger, month, year, *([d1, d2] * 15), d1]
        # Make all Fridays an x
        for day in range(1, 31):
            if dt.datetime(year, month, day).weekday() == FRIDAY:
                # Day 1 is column 3, Day 2 is column 4, etc.
                row[day + 2] = 'x'
        writer.writerow(row)

Output:
Enter year: 2024
Enter month: 8
input the fingerprints: c100
input the fingerprints: c200
input the fingerprints: c300
input the fingerprints: c400

shoft.csv:
fingerprint,month,year,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
c100,8,2024,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x
c200,8,2024,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6
c300,8,2024,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x
c400,8,2024,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,x,x,6,x,6,x,6,x,6

Fridays in 8/2024 are days 2, 9, 16, 23, and 30:


Thank you it worked But I have two new rule fingerprint number 3 and 4 and because busy with it, I didn't reply soon, My condition is for fingerprint number 3 and 4 this two person always working on same days in the week not month for example fingerprint number 3 will work in every (Saturday, Monday, Wednesday) and number 4 works on (Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday) this rule doesn't apply for number 1 and 2 because they always work odd days or even days not carrying about weekdays.

This is my new code https://dpaste.org/LaDMf i pasted there cauz I can't comment too long, I want you to check it say your opinion and the problem that I have is the last day which I can't control because dayCell1 always will be printed.
